# How is Azure Service Bus throttling applied on batch sends?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, throttling

With reference to the below link, I see there is a credit-based system for ASB-standard. For data operations, it is 1 credit per message. If I send a batch of 50 messages, is it 50 credits used for that batch-send operation or 1 credit since I am sending one batch operation?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-throttling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For throttling, each call to `SendAsync` or `ReceiveAsync` counts once against the limit.  In the case of sending, each batch is packaged as a single AMQP message and will consume a single credit.